# Comma between prepositional phrases

Tags: commas

Would there be a comma after the year here? As this is a series of prepositional phrases, I am uncertain about whether the comma should be inserted.

> - *The composer was alleged to have said this to his secretary in 1940, about a seasonal song.*

Comment: It's just a stylistic choice (i.e. - a matter of opinion).

Comment: "About a seasonal song" is a prepositional phrase modifying "this", and I don't think it is really necessary to put a comma there. If you position the prepositional phrase between "this" and "to", it is clearer.

Comment: @Rathony A sentence of 17 words deserves a comma somewhere, and where better than after the date?

Comment: @Rathony No rules. I just like people to understand what I'm saying.

Comment: @WS2 I understand what you mean. I agree with FumbleFingers. It is a stylistic choice.

Comment: Sentences "deserve" commas in ways that reenforce the writer's syntax.  Different style guides recommend different standards of deserving, but what help do you think the comma gives here?

Comment: It is a sort of sentence which is difficult to phrase in a non-awkward form.  You can reorder the phrases six ways from Sunday and it's still either awkward or ambiguous.

Comment: Note that, in thee above example, there's nothing special about the presence of a numerical year, vs any other words denoting a context.  It might as easily be "... to his secretary while riding a bus, about a seasonal song."  (And that would be equally awkward.)

Comment: The word order is awkward: "The composer was alleged to have said this *about a seasonal song* to his secretary in 1940." *about a seasonal song* should be close to "said this".

Comment: @Greybeard I don't understand why people don't use the simplest and the most obvious word choice as you have done. It really gets my goat. :)

Comment: @WS2 I certainly agree that where they don't bring loss of clarity, including that due to comma clutter, commas are valuable in long sentences to aid parsing and, when being read aloud, breathing. Here, I'd say the 'need' is borderline. I'd use one if I wanted to signal a pause (to add emphasis to the second PP, and/or to indicate that it is an afterthought).

Answer (score 0):

Is a comma needed after the year *1940*?

The sentence follows: *The composer was alleged to have said this to his secretary in 1940, about a seasonal song.*

Following the principle that one should avoid breaking up the flow of a sentence as much as possible--and this includes unnecessary commas--it would make sense not to place a comma after *1940.* Certainly it is not necessary.

Perhaps even better would be a simple relocation of the prepositional phrase to the beginning of the sentence, such as this: *In 1940 the composer was alleged to have said this to his secretary about a seasonal song.*

Comment: So sometime in 1940 this allegation was made?  Any idea when the actual event might have occurred -- when he said it?

Comment: Well, how about this: *In 1940 the composer allegedly said this to his secretary about a seasonal song.*

Comment: So why not edit the answer, D?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to put a comma in this situation. It is one thought so it doesn't need to be separated.

Take a note of this [excerpt](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dxVcAAAAMAAJ&q=She%20leaned%20her%20arms%20on%20the%20window%20sill.%20Her%20face%20was%20eager,%20alive,%20dynamic.%20Beside%20her,%20Joanna%20South-%20wood%20seemed,%20somehow,%20a%20little%20dim%E2%80%94a%20tall%20thin%20young%20woman%20of%20twentyseven,%20with%20a%20long%20clever%20face%20and%20freakishly%20plucked%20eyebrows.&dq=She%20leaned%20her%20arms%20on%20the%20window%20sill.%20Her%20face%20was%20eager,%20alive,%20dynamic.%20Beside%20her,%20Joanna%20South-%20wood%20seemed,%20somehow,%20a%20little%20dim%E2%80%94a%20tall%20thin%20young%20woman%20of%20twentyseven,%20with%20a%20long%20clever%20face%20and%20freakishly%20plucked%20eyebrows.&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&printsec=frontcover&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjY5Ii30Yr4AhUEiVwKHY2fDt0Q6AF6BAgKEAI) from Death on the Nile by Agatha Christie

> She leaned her arms on the window sill. Her face was eager, alive,
> dynamic. Beside her, Joanna Southwood seemed, somehow, a little dim -
> a tall thin young woman of twenty - seven, with a long clever face and
> freakishly plucked...

If you notice here, there is extensive use of commas. This is because each thought is a separate one. On the other hand, in your sentence, there is only one thought. Hence, there is no need for a comma. If you were to replace the comma with a full stop (period), the second half of the sentence after the comma would not be a complete sentence. Why? Because it's not a complete, separate thought; it's merely linked to the former part of the sentence.

Answer (score -2):

What we have here is a series of three prepositional phrases and a question about how to best express them all in one sentence so that the meaning is clear and syntactically correct. The big question is, which phrase deserves the most emphasis, or better yet, what is the most logical order for the three prepositional phrases?

I would argue the correct order should be as follows:

> The composer was alleged to have said this about a seasonal song to his secretary in 1940.

Phrasing the sentence this way obviates the perceived need for a comma; in addition, it qualifies the song as a seasonal song earlier in the sentence (which may or may not be important, depending on how many genres of songs the composer is alleged to have discussed with the secretary) and places a certain emphasis on 1940 by having it be the last bit of information the reader sees.

Comment: Arguably, a bigger question, given that they all seem grammatical, is which one gives the emphasis the writer desires.

Comment: Also, there remains a hint of ambiguity. Does 'in 1940' refer to the allegation or the 'saying'?